# Report Headers not repeating on random pages in SSRS 2008 when exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am writing a report in SSRS 2008 that has the following advanced layout:

Static
Static
Static
Static
Group1
    Details
        Static
Static

The settings for the top 4 static rows (which are my headers) are set to RepeatOnNewPage = true, FixedData = true, and KeepWithGroup = After. When viewing the report through SSRS or through VS, the headers repeat correctly on every page. However when the report is exported to PDF, on some report requests, random pages seem to be missing the headers.

Example:
 - Report has 5 pages, headers are missing on page 2/5 but on every other page they should be on.

I've exhausted the Googles, the tubes, and StackOverflow looking for an answer but I have yet to find anything. HALP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I came across this article and hotfix from Microsoft...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977066.  This will bring you to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977443/LN from where you can download the ReportBuilder fixes from "Cumulative Update 6 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1". Installed them on our server and it fixed the issue.
(I guess Reporting Services fixes are included in ReprtBuilder setup?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your static headers into the report Page Header section?

Comment: Unfortunately alot of the headers are nested in odd places in the reports I am working on and this is not possible all the time. I know this will work as a work around, I was just curious if there is a patch or any more information related to the random repeating I am seeing. Thanks for the idea though, I'm more than likely going to have to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug in 2008 for report headers not repeating.  Not sure if it exists in R2 but heres a link that might help.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/956/repeating-column-headers-in-ssrs-2008-and-r2

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately what they are suggesting in the link is essentially what I have been doing so far. I've suggested to our group that we give R2 a try to see what happens, I'll follow up if that works!

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue with VS 2010 and .net 4 When I try to use LocalReport.Render method to render report as PDF, I find table header missing on random pages. I hope MS fix this with a service pack.